# Windows client program refuses to cooperate with linux postgresql database

Tags: linux, windows, postgresql, collation

I have PostgreSQL database engine running on MS-Windows 7 Cz. A client program, which communicates with this pgsql database, runs the MS-Windows 7 Cz, too. The program is installed with US-English language mutation. 
In this default configuration everything goes well. But I want to pair the Windows client program with the PostgreSQL database running on Linux. 
The first try failed, but on both sides no reasonable information was logged. 
I made some comparisons of the Linux db. crated fractions vs. the MS-Windows db. I only found the difference in the COLLATION settings. On Linux db. the default is "cs_CZ.UTF-8", but on the MS-W db. there is "Czech_Czech Republic.1250".

I do really not know what the COLLATION is for, because on the both OS in the dbs. the  default internal encoding is utf-8. Does it means the that the MS-W client speaks to db. using cp1250, while the Linux db. expects the utf8? (Every explanation of COLLATIN speaks about the locale alphabet order?)
It is impossible to change the client behavior, but due to the stability and other database parameters it is highly important to migrate to the Linux server platform.

Can somebody give me some helpful guidelines, how to prepare the Linux PostgreSQL database in ought to be accepted by the MS-Windows client program? The program support team did not (cannot or may be must not) helped me over two month discussion.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide details how it failed. Including actual error messages.

Comment: [Collation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html) just controls sort order. The encoding expected by the server is determined by the [`client_encoding` setting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-CLIENT-ENCODING). Nothing in your question suggests that this is relevant, though; if there's evidence for an encoding mismatch, please include it.

Comment: Yes, I will do. I prepare the analyse of first connect the Client prog. to MS-W pgsql server vs. the same condition first connect to Linux pgsql server. Than I will continue. I admit, the question was posted a bit soon. Thans for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, finally it was very easy: the critical difference between the MS-Windows configuration and the Linux one, it was the Authentication conf module: `pg_hba.conf`! Its content is by default in Linux more tolerant to  developer working on locahost connection:

```
host    all     all   127.0.0.1/32  trust
```

but in MS-Windows the connection rules are very strict:

```
host    all     all   127.0.0.1/32  md5
host    all     all      0.0.0.0/0  md5
```

The client program has no configuration file that may change its behavior.

Lots of polling with Wire-Shark was made to note such simple difference.